# Why won't this let me scan in my find and then unknown?

Tags: c, char, newline, scanf

So, I am trying to make a suvat solver (physics equations) and I need to read in what they need to find(find) and also the thing that they don't know and won't need to know (unknown). It scans in the find yet skips straight to asking about the variables before asking for the unknown. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf ("What are you trying to find:\nDistance, Inital Velocity, Final Velocity, Accelartion or Time\n(Enter first letter)\n");
char find;
scanf("%c", &find);
char unknown;
printf ("What don't you know: \n");
scanf("%c", &unknown);


int i = 0; //initial velocity
int f = 0; //final velocity
int a = 0; //accelaration
int t = 0; //time
int d = 0; //distance

if (((find != 'i') && (find != 'I')) && ((unknown != 'i') && (unknown != 'I'))){
    printf("What is the Inital Velocity: \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
}
if (((find != 'd') && (find != 'D')) && ((unknown != 'd') && (unknown != 'D'))){
    printf("What is the Distance: \n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
}
if (((find != 'f') && (find != 'F')) && ((unknown != 'f') && (unknown != 'F'))){
    printf("What is the Final Velocity: \n");
    scanf("%d", &f);
}
if (((find != 'a') && (find != 'A')) && ((unknown != 'a') && (unknown != 'A'))){
    printf("What is the Accelartion: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
}
if (((find != 't') && (find != 'T')) && ((unknown != 't') && (unknown != 'T'))){
    printf("What is the Time: \n");
    scanf("%d", &t);
}
//printf("find: %c, i: %d, f: %d, a: %d, d: %d, t: %d", find, i, f, a, d, t);
if ((find == 'i') || (find == 'I')) {
    if ((unknown == 's') || (unknown == 'S')) {
        i = a*t - f;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    else if ((unknown == 'a') || (unknown == 'A')) {
        i = ((2*d)/t) - f; 
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    else if ((unknown == 't') || (unknown == 'T')) {
        i = sqrt(pow(f,2)-(2*a*d)); 
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    else if ((unknown == 'f') || (unknown == 'F')) {
        i = (d - (0.5*a*pow(t,2)))/t;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}




return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: use `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: @PrerakSola , Why? That won't solve the problem.

Comment: @PrerakSola It would be worse as you won't be able to skip the enter key without a dirty second call to `getchar()` and it's platform-dependant

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%c", &find);
```

Should be

```
scanf(" %c", &find);
   //  ^ space
```

In your program, `scanf` gets the `\n` from your <kbd>enter</kbd> key press as the second char

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press [a `\n`] after the first `scanf()` is stored in the input buffer and provides the *automatic* input to [next] `scanf()`.

In your code, you need to change

```
scanf("%c", &unknown);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &unknown);    
       ^
       |
     notice here
```

This will *ignore* all the whitespace-like inputs (including the `\n`) and read the first non-whitespace character (i.e., the intended input).

Suggestions:

1. if you don't intend to use `argc` and `argv`, the recommended siganute for `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. You should be using `switch` case instead of prolonged `if-else if-else` condition chain.

Comment: Would it be better to be using scanf or getchar(), for getting in the letter?